# its there a way to connect a mysql table to a mssql table?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I know the question its dumb but I have to ask its there a way to connect a mysql database table to a mssql database table?

I have a mysql table that need to take data from a table in an old SQL 2000 db server its there a way to auto connect them to auto take the data every time its added or updated in the old server?

Is there a way to auto connect them? 
I use an app to copy the data from the old one and add it to the new one every 6 seconds but its a pain because sometimes its closed this littel app and everything becomes a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Not from within MySQL. There's not builtin functionality to connect to a remote database, such as SQL Server,

But it is possible to get SQL Server to communicate to the MySQL database. I had that working with SQL Server 2005 Standard and MySQL 5.1.

I had to setup an ODBC data source on the SQL Server system, using MySQL ODBC driver downloaded from MySQL. (Run odbcad32 to set it up, or you may need the 64-bit equivalent).

I had to enable some configuration options in SQL Server, allowing remote procedure calls and results.

I created a LINKED SERVER in SQL Server 2005 that referenced the ODBC data source. (I think there were some settings I had to tweak in the ODBC data source as well.

With that setup, the "trick" was the actual arcane Transact-SQL constructs, there was a couple of ways to do it, some have better performance than others. (I designed it to not overwhelm memory with a boatload of data, we did the transfers in manageable chunks.)

I didn't have a need to "push" to MySQL from SQL Server; I was doing a "pull" data from MySQL into SQL Server. But I think the same setup could work to perform INSERT and UPDATE statements.

To retrieve a resultset from MySQL into SQL Server, I created a local temporary table (on SQL Server), and pulled the results from the MySQL query to populate that. This worked out to be the most efficient for me.

Some snippets from my stored procedure:

Comments I left about what I need to do to enable the linked server (I only had a need to perform SELECT statements against MySQL.)

```
-- -- to enable RPC for a linked server
-- exec sp_helpserver
-- exec sp_serveroption @server='LOCALHOST_MYSQL_xxxx_RO', @optname='rpc', @optvalue='true'
-- exec sp_serveroption @server='LOCALHOST_MYSQL_xxxx_RO', @optname='rpc out', @optvalue='true'
-- exec sp_helpserver

   -- mysql database from which we retrieve interval data
   DECLARE @linked_server_name NVARCHAR(255)
   SET @linked_server_name = N'[LOCALHOST_MYSQL_xxxx_RO]'

   IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#t_pxxxx') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t_pxxxx
   CREATE TABLE #t_pxxxx ( pxxxx_xxxx_id BIGINT, ...

   DECLARE @s_query NVARCHAR(MAX);
   SET @s_query = 'SELECT r.id AS pxxx_xxxx_id, ... ';

   DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX);
   SET @stmt = N'INSERT INTO #t_pxxxx
   SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(' + @linked_server_name + N','''
     + REPLACE(@s_query,'''','''''') + N''' ) ORDER BY 1';

   -- for debug, show the SQL statement
   -- PRINT N'@stmt: ' + @stmt;

   -- populate #t_pxxxx (local temporary table) from source
   TRUNCATE TABLE #t_pxxxx;
   EXECUTE(@stmt);
```

I tested several variations, using `@tables` and `#tables`, the actual mechanics of how each of those works is somewhat different... what worked out best for me was to create a temporary table (#table)  on SQL Server, and then populating that with results from a MySQL query, and then process from the temporary table.